# Policy for storing configuration files in SVN

Tags: security, svn, version-control, configuration-files

The majority of our C# projects configuration is kept in *.ini files. Mainly these files hold
many sections affecting all aspects of programs behaviour. But besides of regular configuration data some of sections are vulnerable like db connection string or server password. We try to keep this sections in following forms:

```
[Database]
user=testuser
database=testdb
password=
```

But when developer is testing application he must fill the config in order to start application. It is quite common that some of the passwords are commited into version control.
Because these files are indispensable for application they cannot be included in .svnignore.
Probably what I'm looking for is some kind of script (maybe in powershell). That would scan all *.ini files and erase all passwords. The most interesting solution would be adding some external password storage that can be used both to encode and decode passwords in *.ini files.

Answer (score 2):

I always push to store configuration template files in subversion, but not actual configuration files.  So if the configuration file is "config.ini" then I'll check in a "config.ini.template" populated with non-working sample data.

Then to prevent multiple developers from checking in their individual "config.ini" files, I'll add the actual configation file name to the svn:ignore properties list.

This forces the developer to copy the file and modify it appropriately for their environment, but eases the work of that task by not forcing them to find out which fields need to be present.  If you have the time, you can even embed comments into the template file to simplify the meanings of some of the configuration options.

At the top of the file, include the directions of how to configure the system using the template, which should read something like:

```
# *** CONFIGURATION TEMPLATE --- DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE ***
# 1. Make a copy of this file in the same directory with the command "copy config.ini.template config.ini"
# 2. Edit the new copy and follow the rest of the instructions
# 
# Change "this.system.hostname" to the hostname of this system
Hostname = this.system.hostname
# Set the answer "23" to "42"
Answer = 23
```

You get the idea....

If you have problems (or think you might have problems) with people checking in their configuration options over the config.ini.template file, then I'd recommend using "svn lock" on the template file.  However, with the appropriate warning, I've never found it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not answer your question and instead recommend a different approach, assuming it's not too late to change the relevant design.

You should not store passwords in the same files as the rest. Have the application read a dedicated password file (or retrieve the password from a password storage service) in addition to the regular configuration file. This is not just about not storing passwords in svn, but also about not having passwords exposed to shoulder surfing, accidentally mailed or posted when someone asks for help with a non-working configuration, etc.